# How to add names of files of a directory to an array structure using c

Tags: c, arrays, posix

Can anyone tell me how do I save the paths of directories in a directory using array of structures in C. In the code below can anyone tell where is the change needed?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/dir.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE ! FALSE

typedef struct{
    char *path;
}filepath;

struct stat sb;
extern int alpahsort();
int dir_detect(char *name);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    filepath my_array_path[100];
    char *each_name;
    const char *pathname=NULL;
    char success; int ret=0;
    struct direct **files;
    int j=0,i,count,count_dir;
    int file_select();
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <pathname>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("%s\n",argv[1]);
    pathname=argv[1];
    printf("%s\n",pathname);
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *ep;
    dp = opendir (pathname);

    count = scandir(pathname, &files, file_select, alphasort);

    if (dp != NULL)
    {
        while ((ep = readdir (dp))!=NULL){
            printf("the number of files=%d\n",count);
            char *buffer;


            //from here ....
            //my_array_path[i].path=malloc(strlen(buffer+1));
            //strcpy(my_array_path[i].path,buffer);
            my_array_path[i].path=strdup(ep->d_name);
            printf("the name of the file is %s\n",my_array_path[i].path);
            // to here......
```

I wanted to know what I am doing is correct or not. Other code follows.

Comment: Improve your question to get a clear and quick answer.

Comment: We will not write the code for you.  You have all the hints you need. Give it a try.

Comment: No actually i have written the code which was very lengthy and i thought of not putting up the whole thing. I am only stuck at only places where ?? mark has been put.

Comment: Post the code only for the first step that fails, then, in a short minimal complete example (remember to run it in a test directory so simple that you can describe that, too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C provides 2 primary approaches to reading directory contents, similar to the 2 approaches for reading files. Just as with files where you have your choice of reading with low-level `read/write` unbuffered input routines or to read the file using a `FILE*` file-stream, you have those same choices reading directories as well.

With directories you can choose `readdir` where each call to the function will return a **pointer** to a `direct struct` for a file in the directory, moving the file position indicator to the next file to be read. You must repeatedly call `readdir` to access all of the files in the directory.

The second type of directory access relies on `scandir` which returns a pointer to **an array** of `dirent structs` containing all files/dir read from that directory. With `scandir` you need only iterate over the returned array to access each of the files/dirs contained within the directory.

So the primary difference between the two methods is `readdir` returns a single pointer to a file, `scandir` returns a pointer to an array containing all files in the directory.  `scandir` also provides several predefined sorting routines for the files/directory list. (`alphasort`, and `versionsort`) provide a convenient way to sort the `direct struct entries`. Just note that to make use of the predefined sort routines, you must include a define to `_BSD_SOURCE` in your code.

The following shows an example of using `scandir` with the predefined `alphasort` on a small directory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>  /* opendir  */
#include <dirent.h>     /* opendir, readdir, scandir  */
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef _BSD_SOURCE     /* for scandir sort routines  */
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#endif /* _BSD_SOURCE */

int sdfilt (const struct dirent *de);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2 )
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: usage: %s [dirname (default '.')][mode (default 14)\n", argv[0]);


    char *dname = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : ".";   /* directory name to get listing of */
    struct dirent **namelist = NULL;            /* dirent structure to hold listing */
    int ndir = 0;                               /* num dirs scandir returns, -1 err */
    size_t it = 0;                              /* simple iterator for dir list     */

    /* call scandir to fill pointer to array of dirent entries  */
    if ((ndir = scandir (dname, &namelist, sdfilt, alphasort)) < 0)
    {
        perror("scandir");  /* throw error & return on failure  */
        return 1;
    }

    /* print each of the entries in alphasort order  */
    printf ("\nscandir example (alphasort):\n\n");
    for (it = 0; it < ndir; it++)
        printf("  nl[%2zu] %s\n", it, namelist[it]->d_name);

    /* print each entry in reverse sort order & free */
    printf ("\nreverse:\n\n");
    it = ndir;
    while (it--) {
        printf("  nl[%2zu] %s\n", it, namelist[it]->d_name);
        if (namelist[it]->d_name)
            free (namelist[it]);
    }
    free(namelist);

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}

/* simple scandir filter that omit strings and
dot files '.' and '..' from dirent entries */
int sdfilt (const struct dirent *de)
{
    if (strcmp (de->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp (de->d_name, "..") == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/scandir_simple tmp

scandir example (alphasort):

  nl[ 0] bin
  nl[ 1] d1
  nl[ 2] d2
  nl[ 3] rdrmstat.c
  nl[ 4] rmftw-io-out.txt
  nl[ 5] walk-ftw-test.c
  nl[ 6] walk-nftw-test.c

reverse:

  nl[ 6] walk-nftw-test.c
  nl[ 5] walk-ftw-test.c
  nl[ 4] rmftw-io-out.txt
  nl[ 3] rdrmstat.c
  nl[ 2] d2
  nl[ 1] d1
  nl[ 0] bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can done that with dynamic memory allocation.

Declare the variable as,

```
filepath mypath;
```

consider `buffer` having the path of one directory,  then do like this,

```
int i=0;
mypath[i].path=malloc(strlen(buffer+1);
strcpy(mypath[i].path,buffer);
```

Or else `strdup` function,

```
mypath[i].path=strdup(buffer);
```

Then increment that variable to store the next path. And check the condition that is not exceed about the value which you are given in a structure.

```
typedef struct{
  char *path[255];
}filepath;

//in main

filepath mypath;
char *buffer=malloc(255);
int i=0;
strcpy(buffer,"/tmp");
mypath[i].path=malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
strcpy(mypath[i].path,buffer);
printf("path:%s\n",mypath[i].path);
```

Comment: typedef struct{
char *path;
}filepath;
filepath mypath; char *buffer;
                for(i=1;i<count+1;++i)
                {
                my_array_path[i].path=malloc(strlen(buffer+1));
                strcpy(my_array_path[i].path,buffer);
        //      my_array_path[i].path=strdup(buffer);
                printf("the name of the file is %s\n",my_array_path[i].path);
                }

Comment: See the answer. And if you need that for the multiple path , then you have to get the path from user or something else.

Comment: It seems that incrementing " i " was the cause for segmentation fault. Yes you are right. if user is giving the path it is easier but here in the same directory all has to be done.